# All javascript and jquery elements on my django project stopped responding on nginx gunicorn ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, nginx

Up until two days ago, every javascript element on my django powered app was working just fine. But for some reasons beyond me, it all stopped yesterday and i spent the whole of yesterday trying to figure it out

here is my base.html

```
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
<li><a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">Profile</a></li>
<li><p><a href="{% url "edit" %}">Edit your profile</a></li> 
<li><a href="{% url "password_change" %}">Change your password</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/create">Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="/images/likes/">likes</a></li>
   <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

            <li><a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</ul>
</div>


{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
                    <a href="#" class="close">✖</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

    <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}
{% endblock %}
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4   
   /jquery.min.js"></script>                    
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1
  /jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <link href="horbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="horbar.js"></script>



  <script>



    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {

        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        {% block domready %}


        {% endblock %}
        });
        $('.list').hide();
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#two').hide();
        $('#request').on('click', function() {
            $('.list').toggle();

        });

        $('.image-likes').hide();
        $('.count').on('click', function() {
            $('.image-likes').toggle();


   })
</script>
<footer><p>staylplusinc@yahoo.com © 2017 styl+</p></footer>
```

To illustrate, the class "list"($('.list).hide();) is supposed to hide and the appear when the id "#request" is clicked because of the click event attached to it. but "list" does not hide. Every javascript element on my project stopped working.

Like I said, everything was working just fine two days ago.
I am hoping you guys could tell me where the root of such an issue could come from.

Comment: post your static settings from the settings file and your nginx.conf

Comment: open your browser console and check any error is there.

Comment: @Exprator please read edited question

Comment: @itzMEonTV please read edited question